# PySpark: how to load dataframe of edge list into GraphFrame and Networkx graph

Tags: pyspark, graph, networkx

I'm struggling trying to load a dataframe of edge list (i.e. one pair of nodes per line) into a GraphFrames and Networkx graph in order to perform graph visualization and operations.
Here's my DF creation code:

```
schema = StructType([\
    StructField("src", IntegerType(), True),\
    StructField("dest", IntegerType(), True)])

nodes = spark.read.format("csv")\
.option("header", "false")\
.schema(schema)\
.option("sep", "\t")\
.load("/content/data/edgelist.txt")
nodes.show()
```

And this is the dataframe:

```
+---+----+
|src|dest|
+---+----+
|  0| 386|
|  0| 395|
|  0| 451|
|  1|3553|
|  1|3586|
|  1|3587|
|  1|3637|
|  2|3583|
|  3|4930|
|  4|  88|
|  5| 120|
|  5|  13|
|  6|   8|
|  7|   8|
|  8|   9|
|  9|  10|
|  9| 205|
|  9| 208|
|  9|  61|
|  9|  75|
+---+----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Here's the code that doesn't work while trying to load and visualize the graph:

```
def PlotGraph(edge_list):
    Gplot=nx.Graph()
    for row in edge_list.select('src','dst').take(1000):
        Gplot.add_edge(row['src'],row['dst'])
    nx.draw(Gplot, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')

g = GraphFrame(nodes)
PlotGraph(g.edges)
```

Error message says (obviously it wants a vertices dataframe but I don't have those):

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-34-45c0076335ce> in <module>
      5     nx.draw(Gplot, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
      6 
----> 7 g = GraphFrame(nodes)
      8 PlotGraph(g.edges)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e'
```

Thanks for your help. I'm new to all of this.

Comment: Graphframe is a **spark** library and doesn't have visualisations while networkx is local python. what is your end goal?

Comment: I need to explore that graph and also visualize it.

Comment: if the graph is not that big read the csv with pandas (pd.read_csv) and load it to networkx using [from_pandas_edgelist](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html). 

If the graph is big enough you need to use graphframes, you probably can't draw it or at least understand something from it's visualisation.

Comment: Okay that's clear, thank you so much!